# How to get an array from URLSession

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift5

Trying to make a program for a news site. I take information from the site through the api, everything works fine.

The only question is, how do I get this array out of the loop?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var news:[News] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getUsers()            
        print(news)     
    }

    func getUsers() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://prostir.news/swift/api2.php") else         {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    news = try JSONDecoder().decode([News].self, from: data)
                    // print(self.news)
                } catch let error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct News:Codable, CustomStringConvertible{
    let href:String?
    let site:String?
    let title:String?
    let time:String?

    var description: String {
        return "(href:- \(href), site:- \(site), title:- \(title), time:- \(time))"
    }
}
```

Declare news array in your class and assign the response to this array in getUsers method

```
var news:[News] = []

func getUsers(){
    guard let url = URL(string: "https") else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                self.news = try JSONDecoder().decode([News].self, from: data)
                print(self.news)
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: I add the var news:[News] = [] and structure in my controller, I try to print by this command print(news) and I will have "[ ]"

Comment: Print 'newsData' array after 'getUser' method completion.

Comment: Also I call getUsers() and after I print array but result with first

Comment: Structure shouldn't be inside your view controller it should be outside your view controller class. If possible share the URL which you are calling in get users  method.

Comment: I put struct in another file, then I put func getUser after all class in viewcontroller,var news:[News] = [] put in viewcontroller, more in func viewDidLoad() I call getUser() and then I  print(news)(
`class ViewController: UIViewController {
var news:[News] = [] 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         getUsers()
        print(news)
       
    } }
func getUsers(){
    }`

Comment: @ВасяТарас This will never work. URLSession works asynchronously. Do the things you have to do in the closure or add a completion handler.

Comment: @vadian ok, thanks, one question can I put this arrayin the closure to the DataBase(f.e. CoreDate)?

Comment: Of course you can, also inside the closure. @ВасяТарас

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is you are retrieving data asynchronously (e.g. `getUsers` will initiate a relatively slow request from the network using `URLSession`, but returns immediately). Thus this won’t work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getUsers()

    print(news)
}
```

You are returning from `getUsers` before the `news` has been retrieved. So `news` will still be `[]`.

The solution is to give `getUsers` a “completion handler”, a parameter where you can specify what code should be performed when the asynchronous request is done:

```
enum NewsError: Error {
    case invalidURL
    case invalidResponse(URLResponse?)
}

func getUsers(completion: @escaping (Result<[News], Error>) -> Void) {
    let queue = DispatchQueue.main

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://prostir.news/swift/api2.php") else {
        queue.async { completion(.failure(NewsError.invalidURL)) }
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            queue.async { completion(.failure(error)) }
            return
        }

        guard
            let data = data,
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
        else {
            queue.async { completion(.failure(NewsError.invalidResponse(response))) }
            return
        }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
            let news = try decoder.decode([News].self, from: data)
            queue.async { completion(.success(news)) }
        } catch let parseError {
            queue.async { completion(.failure(parseError)) }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Then your view controller can fetch the news, passing a “closure”, i.e. code that says what to do when the asynchronous call is complete. In this case, it will set `self.news` and trigger the necessary UI update (e.g. maybe refresh tableview):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var news: [News] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchNews()
    }

    func fetchNews() {
        getUsers() { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)

            case .success(let news):
                self.news = news
                print(news)
            }

            // trigger whatever UI update you want here, e.g., if using a table view:
            //
            // self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        // but don't try to print the news here, as it hasn't been retrieved yet
        // print(news)
    }
```